# Building Task queue: RPC vs MPI

Tags: python, mpi, distributed-computing, rpc, task-queue

What are the pros and cons of building a distributed task queue with RPC vs MPI ( ex. Python's `celery` )? From what I have seen, the all task queues are implemented by queuing messages in a task queue, them using multiprocessing & multithreading to consume the tasks in the queue. So using messages seems to be the standard. Is it even possible to use RPC to construct such task queue? And why would it wouldn't it be a good idea?